# SSL is cracked. What is the alternative?

Tags: encryption, tls

According to Der Spiegel:

> SSL should be cracked
>
> Exactly how much the two intelligence agencies can actually read along
>   from the encrypted traffic in the network, is not entirely clear. But
>   the reports can imagine that a large part of the communication and
>   data transmission in the Internet is not secure, at least in terms of
>   commercial services. Even in cases where firms designate a transaction
>   as safe to their customers, this could be full of holes - whether
>   emails, chats, online banking, transactions or data transmitted with a
>   supposedly "safe" route from A to B are. The secret disponer for
>   example on ways to crack much used online protocols such as HTTPS,
>   voice-over-IP and SSL. So stand up in the address bar of the browser
>   shortcut HTTPS - for example, when entering a password - is that
>   unlike previously widely assumed no guarantee of a safe data
>   transmission.

source: http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/nsa-und-britischer-geheimdienst-knacken-systematisch-verschluesselung-a-920710.html

SSL, voice over encryption, HTTPS are cracked by NSA and GCQH.

Which alternative to SSL do we how now? Is there something I can use for my websites so the customers will be safe? Is such technology available for a casual eshops and websites?

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the question you suggested as `This question already has an answer here:` I am asking specifically on SSL alternative not what services can be creacked by NSA or GCQH or others.

Comment: At this point, the verifiable details as to what has and hasn't been broken and/or pwned by the NSA are still *very* fuzzy. As such, your question - which essentially is asking "What alternatives to SSL can I use that *haven't* been compromised by the NSA?" - is currently unanswerable without broad speculation. Rather than making this a dead-end closed question though, Terry & Rory decided to link it to the canonical question for today's NSA news so that later visitors (and yourself) can get more details on what we *do* know about the NSA's capabilities and our ability to work around them.

Comment: Well, that linked question (and accepted answer which happens to be by that question's OP too) is as speculative as every other related question and answer as it's all based on personal opinion. Until the NSA confirms or denies what they can or can not to, no one can know for sure. It's all ***opinion***, based on media-hyped leaks (which could be fake btw. - but NSA won't confirm or deny that either).